Running multiple functions in only one file
I have a sheet with 3 tabs, and a total of 9 'set formula' app script functions across those sheets, each with a daily trigger.
As this sheet powers a looker studio dash, I also need to have 9 'set value' functions to keep the columns headings consistent and stop the looker studio from breaking. I'd like to avoid having 18 separate files/triggers, and have one for each sheet each containing 6 (differently named) functions
When I try running a file with more than one function (see below) it only runs the top function - though they both work when run from separate files.
If love to know if there's a way to do this all together.
Example functions below
function levelheading(){

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Source');

 var cell = sheet.getRange("AB1");

 cell.SetValue('Level');

}





function level(){

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Source');

 var cell = sheet.getRange("AB12:AB");

 cell.setFormula("VLookup(B2,'Reference'!A:E,5, False");

}


Welcome to Stack Overflow. The code in the question has syntax errors, so it will not run in Google Apps Script. What is the source of this code?

why not just create one trigger that fires every hour.  You can get the data and time and other data from the event object.

Unless I'm missing something you can only select one function for each trigger? It's also for hygiene/organization I'd prefer to have fewer triggers

Thanks - syntax errors are due to typos. As mentioned all the functions currently work independently

I don't know your full scenario, and why you need all those modifications so regularly; but maybe you can consolidate your functions in only one or two. For example, your two example ones can be reduced to:
function levelConsolidated(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Source');

sheet.getRange("AB1").setValue('Level');

sheet.getRange("AB12:AB").setFormula("VLookup(B2,'Reference'!A:E,5, False");

}

Or create a function that launches all the others:
function launcher() {
  level()
  levelheading()
  anotherFunction()
  etcetera()

}


Interesting, I hadn't considered that consolidating it into one function would work...thanks so much, I'll give that a go!
